# Nginx Daemonset - How do I select which IP address to bind to?

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress, daemonset

I have a Docker Enterprise k8 bare metal cluster running on Centos8, and following the official docs to install NGINX using manifest files from GIT: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/installation/installation-with-manifests/

The pod seems to be running:

```
kubectl -n nginx-ingress describe pod nginx-ingress-fzr2j

Name:         nginx-ingress-fzr2j
Namespace:    nginx-ingress
Priority:     0
Node:         server.example.com/172.16.1.180
Start Time:   Sun, 16 Aug 2020 16:48:49 -0400
Labels:       app=nginx-ingress
              controller-revision-hash=85879fb7bc
              pod-template-generation=2
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: privileged
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.225.27
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.225.27
```

But my issue is the IP address it has selected is a 192.168.225.27. This is a second network on this server. How do I tell nginx to use the 172.16.1.180 address that is has in the Node: part?
The Daemset config is :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-ingress
     #annotations:
       #prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
       #prometheus.io/port: "9113"
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: nginx-ingress
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:edge
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx-ingress
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          hostPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
          hostPort: 443
        - name: readiness-port
          containerPort: 8081
       #- name: prometheus
         #containerPort: 9113
        readinessProbe:
         httpGet:
           path: /nginx-ready
           port: readiness-port
         periodSeconds: 1
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
          runAsUser: 101 #nginx
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
            add:
            - NET_BIND_SERVICE
        env:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        args:
          - -nginx-configmaps=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/nginx-config
          - -default-server-tls-secret=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/default-server-secret
```

I can't see any configuration option for which IP address to bind to.

Comment: Running ifconfig, I can see that the 192.168 network is actually Calico which is running in this cluster. 
vxlan.calico: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet 192.168.225.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 192.168.225.0

if that makes a difference. I still need nginx to bind to the host ip address and not calico

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are likely looking for is [`hostNetwork: true`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#podspec-v1-core), which:

> Use the host's network namespace. If this option is set, the ports that will be used must be specified. Default to false

```yaml
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      containers:
      - image: nginx/nginx-ingress:edge
        name: nginx-ingress
```

You would only then need to specify a bind address if it bothered you having the Ingress controller bound to all addresses on the host. If that's still a requirement, you can have the Node's IP injected via the [`valueFrom:` mechanism](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables):

```
...
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: MY_NODE_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          status.hostIP
```